# question about progmem

Tags: flash, progmem

I have a problem understanding the following code:

```cpp
PROGMEM  prog_uint16_t x={1232,3232,43343};
rawlen = pgm_read_word_near(x);
memcpy_P(uSendBuff, pfSendBuff+1, rawlen * sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Why do we need this? -

```cpp
rawlen * sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Why not this? -

```cpp
memcpy_P(uSendBuff, pfSendBuff+1, sizeof(rawlen));
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably because x is an **array** of integers (although in the code you posted you miss the '[]'), thus memcpy_p should run over `rawlen` integers, each integer occupies `sizeof(uint16_t)` bytes, hence `rawlen * sizeof(uint16_t)` bytes in program memory space.